# Delete a row from a JList

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jlist, sql-delete

I am making a project and for this project I need to delete a specific row from a Jlist. The Jlist is filled with data from a database.

Now when I click my Jbutton I can delete a row from the column code, but when I want to delete a new row I need to change the query in the new code.

ActionPerformed:

```
@Override
    public void Delete() {
        Connection conn;
        String sql = "DELETE FROM OEFENINGEN WHERE CODE = '5'"; 

        try{
            conn = OpenConnection();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            int result = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            if(result > 0){
                System.out.println("Record Delete");
            } else{
                System.out.println("Record NOT Delete");
            }
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stmt != null){
                try{
                    stmt.close();
                }catch (SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  
            }
        }
        }   
    }
```

I want when you select a random row in the JList he delete the row from the database and Jlist when you click the Jbutton.

Comment: After delete the row from database, reload the JList with the actual data from database.

Comment: On the moment i am deleting not a random selected row but WHERE CODE = '5' so he is deleting only the row where code is 5 and not 6 7 or 8. If i want to delete 6 i need to change it in WHERE CODE = '6' but i want to delete 6 without changing the code just select it in the JList and click the Button.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? You don't know how to delete a record from the database, or how to delete a row from the JList, or how to determine the currently selected row in JList?

Comment: Note that you should not update your DB on the Event Dispatch Thread. Long running operations should happen on a background thread. Consult the [Swing concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more info

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that each row of the list is an actual Object that represents the data in the database (or is at least carrying the required information to be identifiable)

Create yourself an [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), pass a reference of the `JList``ListModel` to it.

When the `actionPerformed` method is fired, check which rows are selected, extract the row data from the `ListModel` and call you delete method.  In the delete method, use the information from the rows to identify criteria for the delete statement